# delete selected row in grid tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I delete a selected row and add a new row in a grid by pressing a button?

I have already created two buttons with their respective functions:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def get_val(row, col):
    table[row][col] = entry_vars[row][col].get()

def delete_row(row, col):    #   how to delete selected row   need code 
    return

def add_row(row, col):  #   how to Add New  row need code 
          return  
    
root = tk.Tk()
height = 10
width = 10

table = [['' for i in range(height)] for j in range(width)]

entry_vars = []

for i in range(height):
    row_vars = []
    for j in range(width):
        vary = tk.StringVar()
        var.set(table[i][j])
        entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
        entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, row=i, col=j: get_val(row, col))
        row_vars.append(var)
    entry_vars.append(row_vars)
        
    b = Button(root, text="Add New Row", command= lambda row=i, col=j: add_row(row, col), width=10)
    b.grid(row=20, column=0)
     
    b1 = Button(root, text="delete Row", command= lambda row=i, col=j: delete_row(row, col), width=10)
    b1.grid(row=20, column=1)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have so many typo error. vary not var.

Comment: You cannot delete row. Simply use `.configure` to update or delete string. Because you set constant height or width.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code with the missing funs and changed some things as needed. I hope you find it useful.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


def get_val(row, col):
    values[row][col] = entry_vars[row][col].get()


def delete_row():
    global height
    height -= 1

    # get all cells in a row and "forgets" them
    for cell in root.grid_slaves(row=height):
        cell.grid_forget()
    # delete the row's values and entry variables
    values.pop()
    entry_vars.pop()


def add_row():
    # the height is not a constant since rows could be added, and it is the best variable to indicate a new row's id
    global height
    row = height
    height += 1

    values.append(["" for _ in range(initial_width)])
    # The code you wrote to make initial rows
    row_vars = []
    for j in range(initial_width):
        var = tk.StringVar()
        # removed the var.set since there is no initial values now
        entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
        entry.grid(row=row, column=j)
        entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda event, r=row, c=j: get_val(r, c))
        row_vars.append(var)
    entry_vars.append(row_vars)


root = tk.Tk()
height = 0

# changed to initial for clarity
initial_height = 10  
initial_width = 10  

# changed the table variable to be dynamic and renamed it 
values = []
# no change after here
entry_vars = []

for i in range(initial_height):
    add_row()

b = Button(root, text="Add New Row", command=add_row, width=10)
b.grid(row=20, column=0)
b1 = Button(root, text="delete Row", command=delete_row, width=10)
b1.grid(row=20, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```